# Plotting error when plotting multiple points with asymmetric errorbars using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=np.array([1,2,3])
y=np.array([2,4,5])
errors = [[0.1,0.2,0.3],[0.5,0.1,0.4]] #[lower_errorbars, upper_errorbars]
```

When I plot just two points, they look fine (see dimond points on plot below)

```
plt.errorbar(x[:2]+0.5,y[:2]+0.5,np.array(errors).T[:2,:],fmt='d')
```

But when I plot three points, an end cap is shown at each errorbar length with the line wandering somewhere else (see round points).

```
plt.errorbar(x,y,np.array(errors).T,fmt='o')
plt.show()
```

Please help me fix this issue!

I don't have enough reputation at the moment to attach the plot that this code makes. I'll work on it, but would really appreciate some help in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the transforms should not be performed because the errors array is already in the correct format.

```
plt.errorbar(x[:2]+0.5,y[:2]+0.5,np.array(errors)[:2,:],fmt='d')
plt.errorbar(x,y,np.array(errors),fmt='o')
```